# PHP variable in mySQL containing mySQL equasion

Tags: php, mysql, variables

The following is a mySQL query containing the initial query followed by some additional criteria.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE telephone > 0 AND last_known_voting_intention = 'P' OR last_known_voting_intention = 'A'");
```

I want to pass the additional criteria from another page and included in a PHP variable.

```
$criteria = "AND last_known_voting_intention = 'P' OR last_known_voting_intention = 'A'";
```

How do I then include that in the mySQL query.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE telephone > 0 $criteria");

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE telephone > 0 ".$criteria);
```

These 2 do not appear to work.

Comment: I suppose the original query (without separating $criteria) worked all right?

Comment: Do the first query work? You do know that AND have higher precedence than OR, right?

Comment: Of course. ) Somehow I was still looking at this query with all this long 'OR'red stuff replaced by simple 'IN' condition. I'd suggest submitting your comment as an answer. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original query looks like it should to work, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's one of PHP's mysteries.

What you could do is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM electors WHERE telephone > 0";
$criteria = " AND last_known_voting_intention = 'P' OR last_known_voting_intention = 'A'";

if (!empty($criteria))
{
  $sql .= $criteria; // Append it to SQL query
}

mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: I'd rewrite the $criteria using `IN`.